# Future in the same class

Tags: c++11, future

```
Class2 Bank::function(const Object& object, const std::string& string)
{
    ....
    return objectClass2;
}
```

I have a function which initialize in async like:

```
auto fu = std::async(std::launch::async, &Class::function, this, object, string);
```

After

```
Class2 newObjectClass2 = fu.get();
```

And i have error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
>   Error C2512   'Class2': no appropriate default constructor
>   available ConsoleApplication18    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 14.0\vc\include\future 263 Build

Without future, my programm works well, all tests are passed.

This problem exist only in VC++, but in other compiler run ok.